# Staircase function

Tags: functions

For some reason, I cannot think of a staircase function to satisfy the following set of points:

{1,0}
{2,0}
{3,0}
{4,0}
{5,0}
{6,0}
{7,0}
{8,1}

The idea is that we want a function to express the week that correlates to a given day; e.g. 14 days is 1 week and 7 days, as opposed to 2 weeks and 0 days.

Comment: The last paragraph confuses me. What do you want as result in weeks and days for $14d$?

Comment: $f(x)=\Big\lfloor\frac{x-1}{7}\Big\rfloor$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $H(x)$ be the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function). Then
$$ f(x) = H(x - 7.5)
$$
satisfies your properties.

Answer (score 0):

I think you look for a function like $\displaystyle f(x) = \left\lfloor \frac{\max(x - 1, 0)}{7}\right\rfloor$.